# Laravel Socket.io Cross-Origin denied

Tags: node.js, laravel, nginx, socket.io, cors

I'm trying to deploy my laravel app with socket.io and I have everything up and running. Node, redis, etc. but when socket event is fired I get this exact error message.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Lbe2fnV. Cross-origin redirection denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy.
```

I have gone into my nginx config file and added the following:

```
upstream app_yourdomain {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
    keepalive 8;
}
location ~* \.io {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
     proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade; 
}
```

but it doesn't do anything.

How can I get rid of the cross-orgin error?
My biggest success came from this post

[NodeJS server on DigitalOcean using socket.io returns connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39119682/nodejs-server-on-digitalocean-using-socket-io-returns-connection-refused)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the origins property like so.

```
io.set('origins', 'http://localhost:3000');
```

You can put in every url you allow to get the request from for example

```
io.set('origins', 'http://google.com:80');
```

or allow all

```
io.set('origins', '*:*');
```

[More about the origin property can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15771805/how-to-set-socket-io-origins-to-restrict-connections-to-one-url/21711242#21711242)

Comment: I did that and the error went away, but now it doesn't work. It doesn't give any error messages either. When I'm receiving the socket this is what I'm putting. `var socket = io("http://localhost:3000");`

Comment: @CriticalTheWizard Try setting the origin property to *:* just for testing purposes? does it work after that or?

Comment: i was working on earlier and I found the I had to put `var socket = io("http://mywebsite.com:3000") ` because localhost was actually connecting to my local dev server I had running.  My problem now is the website can connect to the socket (that's what the socket debugger says) but it can't receive any data. It keeps writing a ping message, flushes 1 packet, then gets the correct type with data as undefined.

Comment: That sounds more like a code error can u post your code? Or make a new question?

Comment: [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41497621/laravel-socket-io-production-server-not-receiving-data)