# Laravel Socket.io Connected but not receiving data

Tags: node.js, laravel, redis, socket.io

I set up a working node server and Redis server on my local environment and was able to successfully use socket.io with Laravel. But when I tried to push my changes to the production server I realized that socket.io was not working properly.

When I typed in the following command in the Google Chrome console to debug socket.io it said that it had established a connection, but it could never received data.

```
localStorage.debug = "socket.io-client:socket"
```

I knew it was a problem with the redis server because one, it said it was connected to the socket. And two, if I wrote die and dump in the event class, it successfully died.

```
namespace App\Events;

class MyEvent implements ShouldBroadcast{
  public function broadcastOn(){
        dd("Successfully reached event");
        return new Channel($this->channel.'-channel');}}
```

Finally, I knew it couldn't be either of my servers, because I was able to curl both of the ports for the redis server and the node server from local and remote hosts.

**This is an edited post that shows my debugging process. My original post was too vague because I did not know how to debug this issue, but if you would like to see it, view the edits.**

Comment: I had some similar issues a while back. Take a look at this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-set-up-node-socket-io-and-redis

Comment: I'm still having the same problem after doing that.

Comment: all I get is this in the console.
`socket.io-client:socket transport is open - connecting +0ms`

Comment: Can you share your `CreatedPost` event?

Answer (score 0):

As embarrassing as this is, I found the solution. The reason it was detecting the socket, but not going through was because I forgot that environment variables got reset. So this whole time I was running this as my environment variables.

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

when I should have been using this.

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```